# PHP API + jQuery AJAX call JSON Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, oop

I am trying to make a form that consumes an API to store information in my Database.

But the file **app.php** it's not returning anything. There is where I handle to communicate the API with the DB.

I am getting this error in the Developer Extension in my frontend form:

> **SyntaxError: JSON.parse:** unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Just for testing I tried to do `var_dump($response); die;` in **app.php** and it shows me the text correctly.

My **app.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

require 'autoload.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
        case 'set':
            $data = new Data;
            $data->name  = $_REQUEST['name'];
            $data->email = $_REQUEST['email'];
            $data->phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $response['id'] = $data->save();

            return json_encode($response);
            break;

        default:
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            break;
    }
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

My app.js file:

```
    var data = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        action: 'set'
    };

    var sentData = sendData(data);

    if(sentData) {
        alert("OK");
        resetFields();
    } else {
        alert("NOT OK");
    }

function sendData(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'app/app.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            return response;
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            return xhr.responseText
        }
    })
}
```

So, where is the error?

Comment: You have a syntax error, which wont return json.

Comment: So... where is it?

Comment: You can see from above `header('Content-Type: application/json);`

Comment: You should also use `exit(json_encode($response));` not `return json_encode($response);`

Comment: The first error you saw wasn't that, but the exit() helped. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `return`, you should echo out your json, if it's the end of the script execution you can use `exit`.

```
<?php

namespace App;

require 'autoload.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
        case 'set':
            $data = new Data;
            $data->name  = $_REQUEST['name'];
            $data->email = $_REQUEST['email'];
            $data->phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $response['id'] = $data->save();

            exit(json_encode($response));
            break;

        default:
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            break;
    }
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```